# making python module work for different users in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, pip

I have two users in my ubuntu : anubhav and ggc_user.

I installed a python module dlr using pip.
When I switch to user anubhav and import dlr, I get expected output:

```
anubhav@Surface-Pro-3:/usr/bin$ python3
Python 3.7.5 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:50:52) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dlr

CALL HOME FEATURE ENABLED
```

But when i switch to ggc_user using `sudo -u ggc_user` , I get an error when I import dlr:

```
anubhav@Surface-Pro-3:/usr/bin$ sudo -u ggc_user bash
ggc_user@Surface-Pro-3:/usr/bin$ python3
Python 3.7.5 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:50:52) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dlr
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:80: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.3) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!
  RequestsDependencyWarning)
```

How to make the module work for both users?

Comment: How did you install it? Where?

Comment: i installed it using pip install dlr after i switched to user anubhav

Comment: Users don't share installed pagckages by default, for what should be obvious reasons. It can be done, but the absolutely simplest fix on your personal computer is to install system-wide, as `root`.

Comment: do u mean 'sudo pip install dlr'?

Comment: That should do it, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `--system` arg

```sh
sudo python3.7 -m pip install X --system
```