# Installing python3 package 'matplotlib' for all users in Rocky Linux 8 server

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, matplotlib

I'm newly in charge of system administration tasks, with a Rocky Linux 8 (Rocky Linux 8.6) server that has a couple dozen users. I want all users to be able to use `numpy` and `matplotlib` in Python3 on this server.

I've recently learned (through the warning given when `pip install`ing as root...) that I should NOT be using pip as the root user, so I've instead installed `numpy` using yum as root: `yum install python3-numpy` - this works fine.

However, when I try (as root): `yum install python3-matplotlib`, I get the following:

```
    Error: 
     Problem: conflicting requests
      - nothing provides libqhull.so.7()(64bit) needed by python3-matplotlib-3.0.3-4.el8.x86_64
    (try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

How do I get `libqhull` installed on my system? Or - do I need to do something different for all users to have access to numpy and matplotlib in Python3?

Comment: check this threads https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66243583/making-python-module-work-for-different-users-in-ubuntu-18-04 ............Thread 2 https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/435495/giving-access-to-user-installed-python-distribution-to-another-linux-user   ........Thread 3 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36898474/how-to-install-a-module-for-all-users-with-pip-on-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seemed to get this fixed, but goodness I'm not sure if this is the best or even a good method, but I seemed to have fixed my problem.

I have another Rocky Linux 8.6 server that had already had matplotlib installed. On this other server, `yum list installed` showed:

`libqhull.x86_64   2015.2-5.el8    @powertools`,

seeing that the repository `powertools` had it.

So, on my Rocky Linux 8.6 server mentioned in the original question, I did:

`yum install --enablerepo "powertools" python3-matplotlib`

And it `matplotlib` installed and is available for all users. Immediate problem solved!

Comment: Enabling this repo allowed me to install GNU Octave as well!